# Phonegap + JQuery Mobile application randomly gets stuck on current page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

We are developing a Phonegap application with JQuery mobile that randomly gets stuck on the current page. After starting the application, a few minutes it works fine, but after some time it just doesn't navigate to another page (either through direct link, window.history or $("body").pagecontainer). On the current page everything continues to work fine (inputs, buttons, even ajax requests), and it happens on every page, apparently not related to any concrete user interaction.

Comment: you need to provide additional info like code snippet, phonegap versions, device tested on android/IOS/Windows, physical device or emulator used.

Comment: Thenk you for your response. We use the latest version of Phonegap/Cordova/JQuery mobile. We have tested the app on different Android devices and emulators, with different Android versions, but the situation is the same. Instead, in browser window it doesn't happen, only on mobile devices and emulators. No error message is displayed in browser or weinre log either, it just doesn't navigate.

Comment: We have also noticed that only internal, anchor links stop working, the ones to different html files don't (for faster page transitions we have included every page into a single index.html file as suggested).